# Array sort by value in words

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I want to sort the values by ascending order.

I tried `ksort`, and other sorting examples.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tenure] => 1 year to less than 2 years
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tenure] => 10 years to less than 15 years
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tenure] => 15 years or more
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tenure] => 2 years to less than 5 years
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [tenure] => 5 years to less than 10 years
        )

)
```

I want to sort the tenure values of the above array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use core [array_multisort](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'tenure'),   
SORT_ASC, SORT_NATURAL, $array);
```

https://3v4l.org/cXNQH.

Comment: This is good. I forget that `array_column` works on arrays of objects too.

Answer (score 2):

Since your values all start with numbers, you can convert them to integers and sort on those using [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) { return (int)$a->tenure - (int)$b->tenure; });
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [0] => stdClass Object (
    [tenure] => 1 year to less than 2 years
  )
  [1] => stdClass Object (
    [tenure] => 2 years to less than 5 years
  )
  [2] => stdClass Object (
    [tenure] => 5 years to less than 10 years
  )
  [3] => stdClass Object (
    [tenure] => 10 years to less than 15 years
  )
  [4] => stdClass Object (
    [tenure] => 15 years or more
  )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/2QJPO)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk`, `ksort`, You can change `object` to `array` using

```
$arr = (array) $object;
```

after that try this

```
$res=[];
array_walk($arr, function($v, $k) use (&$res){
  $key = substr($v['tenure'], 0, strspn($v['tenure'], "0123456789"));
  $res[$key] = $v;
});
ksort($res);
```

[Working Demo](https://3v4l.org/cOEXE)